# Function parameter not defined in react native

Tags: react-native

What is the correct way to create and call a function in real native. I tried to create the following function

```
class Test extends Component {
    ...
    toDate(dateStr) {
        const [day, month, year] = dateStr.split('-');
        return new Date(year, month - 1, day);
    }
    ...
    render() {
    const {
      MyDate
    } = this.state.MyData;
    const dtField = new Date(this.toDate(MyDate));
    ...
}
```

It is returning the error: TypeError: dateStr is undefined

Answer (score 0):

That way that you are using, it's a right way, but the issues about the dateStr is undefined, it's mean that the value that are you send it as an argument is not defined yet, probably you must have a default state, like this.

```
class Test extends Component {

    state = { // <-- THIS
        MyData: {
            MyDate: ''
        }
    }

    toDate(dateStr) {
        const [day, month, year] = dateStr.split('-');
        return new Date(year, month - 1, day);
    }

    render() {
        const {
          MyDate
        } = this.state.MyData;
        const dtField = new Date(this.toDate(MyDate));
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, my state has value because I display it.

Comment: It's funny, I inserted a console.log(MyDate) before the New Date(...). It calls shows the log 3 times. Th first 2 undefined and the third time with a value. Why is it calling the render() multiple times?

Comment: Well, it can be for several things, one of them is calling setState method, every time you call that method will be call the render method or you are sending a key to that component, each time you change the key the component will be re mounted, so the render method will be called again.